# MySQL indexing issue when trying to search for a part of a string/word

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, full-text-search

### What we're running into:

Engine: `MySQL`.

We've been working on a filter where an user can search for a reference number. However, we've ran into an issue with performance on bigger data sets.

We need to search for partial words; say we have the reference `AB12345678` - the user wants to find this reference by either searching `AB`, `B123`, `1234` or any other combination which contains part of this string.

We have an `INDEX` on reference & date

We're currently using `LIKE %STRING%`, but this cannot be indexed - and performance is bad in certain situations:

**(1)** When we search for `AB` we get a fast result.

**(2)** When we search for `AB12345678` we get a slow result.

Both situations have `ORDER BY date` & `LIMIT`.

When we turn off either `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` with situation **(2)**, we also get a fast result.

A slow result is around 14-15 seconds of query execution time.

The dataset contains around 300k results.

### What we've tried so far:

We tried implementing `FULLTEXT` indexes and `MATCH .. AGAINST` queries, however `MATCH .. AGAINST` doesn't allow us to search for both sides, the `*` wildcard is only allowed at the end of the input string.

We've also tried removing the `INDEX` on `date`. This gave us faster results (around 1/3th of the time) however, the query still took around 4-5 seconds.

We're kinda lost on the best implementation that can improve our performance on this query and how we can best solve it right now. What method should we use to get our performance back and be able to search on both sides?

Below is part our query which has slow results (we removed the `SELECT` part):

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM orders o0_
WHERE 1=1
AND o0_.customer_id = 130
AND (o0_.reference LIKE '%AB12345678%')
ORDER BY date4 DESC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Can you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW INDEX` and `EXPLAIN` ? We need more information to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get rid of the *leading* wildcard (%), do so; then we can discuss better indexes.

Meanwhile, use `INDEX(customer_id, date4)`; it has *some* chance of speeding up the query.

What version are you running?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the suggestion for that index. It already speed up more then half the query time, not perfect but a lot better! I can't however share more in-depth information about the table from the company, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Trigram indexing is a solution for indexing partial strings, but you have to implement a lot of code yourself. MySQL has no builtin support for this.

PostgreSQL has support for trigram indexing in an extension. See for example https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/08/postgresql-example-of-trigram-index-for-full-text-search-using-pg_trgm-extension/. But I don't know if the extension is supported. Some blogs older than five years or more about extended features often end up being abandonware. And of course I understand you are using MySQL, so you would either need to develop an equivalent extension for MySQL yourself, or else switch your database to PostgreSQL, which is a challenge.

Other than this, all I can suggest is to take a step back and reconsider how you are storing and searching the data. It might require a major rethink.

Comment: I realize this question is old.